# Can Log Gabor Filters be used on an edge detected image

Tags: image-processing

i'm doing a project on log gabor filters, can i use log gabor filter on an edge detected image for feature extraction,and use these features for classification by ANN

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE. What is the objective? What are you trying to achieve? What are the type of images are? Pl elaborate all these if you expect this question to be answered.

Comment: i want to classify healthy and unhealthy diastole and systole from a dataset (which includes both normal and abnormal cases) of 300 echocardiographic (2D) images and i'm planning to use log gabor filter for feature extraction. My doubt is whether  i can use log gabor filter on an edge detected image